# Number return integer instead of float

Tags: sql-server

I use the below code to get today currency from SQL Server.

```
WITH TodayCurrency(RateDate, Currency, Rate, USDR)
     AS (SELECT T0.RateDate,
                T0.Currency,
                T0.Rate,
                Cast(Round(Cast(T0.Rate AS FLOAT) / Cast(T1.Rate AS FLOAT), 4) AS FLOAT) USDR
         FROM   ORTT T0
                JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM   ORTT
                      WHERE  RateDate = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())
                             AND Currency = 'USD') T1
                  ON T0.RateDate = T1.RateDate
         WHERE  T0.RateDate = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()))
SELECT *
FROM   TodayCurrency
```

Result is below and it is what I expect.  I will use USDR to convert all transaction to USD

```
RateDate        Currency Rate   USDR
14-Jan-18       EUR     1.5111  1.1832
14-Jan-18       HKD     0.1635  0.128
14-Jan-18       RMB     0.1936  0.1516
14-Jan-18       USD     1.2771  1
```

But, when I use it to join link with transactions, all transaction USDR return 1.0000

```
WITH TodayCurrency(RateDate, Currency, Rate, USDR)
     AS (SELECT T0.RateDate,
                T0.Currency,
                T0.Rate,
                Cast(Round(Cast(T0.Rate AS FLOAT) / Cast(T1.Rate AS FLOAT), 4) AS FLOAT) USDR
         FROM   ORTT T0
                JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM   ORTT
                      WHERE  RateDate = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())
                             AND Currency = 'USD') T1
                  ON T0.RateDate = T1.RateDate
         WHERE  T0.RateDate = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()))
SELECT ODPO.*,
       TodayCurrency.USDR
FROM   ODPO
       LEFT JOIN TodayCurrency
              ON ODPO.DocCur = TodayCurrency.Currency
```

ODPO.DocCur is transaction currency which is EUR, HKD, RMB or USD.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have Currency other than `USD` in `ODPO` table ?

Comment: Yes, I can see other currency on ODPO table, for example EUR. The return is 1 for EUR.